# autocomplete to return results within a radius

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

In my google maps autocomplete server side query, i'm trying to return results around or near a latitude and longitude, I've tried this so far

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=<<KEY>>&types=geocode&sensor=true&language=en&location=40.64131109999999%2C-73.77813909999998&strictBounds=true&radius=10&input=london
```

WHERE `40.64131109999999%2C-73.77813909999998` is the latitude and longitude of JFK - John F. Kennedy International Airport.

But when the search string is london, results still show. Any idea how to limit results within a certain radius / boundary or country? Thanks

Comment: `strictBounds` is incorrect.

Comment: @MrUpsidown what do i do? or what do i add ?

Comment: Read the documentation! It's your best friend. URL parameters are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my findings on your URL request:

- You have included `strictBounds=true` which is incorrect since parameters are case sensitive hence it will be omitted in the request. It should be `strictbounds` instead.
- You also do not need the `=true` because adding the parameter `strictbounds` is enough to restrict the places returned  within the defined `location` and `radius`.
- The value of `radius` that you have included is too small (10) which may lead to `ZERO_RESULTS`

You may try this request instead:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=london&location=40.64131109999999,-73.77813909999998&radius=10000&components=country:US&strictbounds&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```